# Load site based on cookie value in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, header, location, reload

I need to load site based on cookie, i write code to validate that like this.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])){
    $domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    setcookie('cookie','US', time() + 31536000, '/', $domain);
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   // reload
}
```

But when cookie created first time i got error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ9qe.png)

Comment: My first guess is that the domain isn’t matching what the browser is seeing. Inspect the headers sent in your browser tools. Do you really need that parameter? It is usually only needed when you want to control sub-domain access.